# Persisting RecylerView Adapter Through Activity Changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onrestoreinstancestate

I have created a simple recyler view in an activity (say, A1) where user can add/delete the items in the reclycler view. I now am trying to save it while navigating to second activity (say, A2) and restore it while moving back (A2 -> A1), but am unable to do so. While coming back to A1 from A2, the recycler view is initialized again, losing all the user modified data. Requesting your help with the same.

I have tried the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods, but when I navigate to A1, the onRestoreInstanceState is not being called. I can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
//rv is the recycler view I am trying to save
//STATE_KEY and TAG are strings for Log statement

Parcelable rv_state;

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

        rv_state = rv.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
        state.putParcelable(STATE_KEY, rv_state);
        Log.d(TAG, " on save rvstate setup = " + rv_state); //rv_state not null here
    }

    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) { //never called
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        Log.d(TAG, "b4 onRestoreinstance state check " + state);
        if (state != null)
            Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreinstance in if state check " + state);
        rv_state = state.getParcelable(STATE_KEY);
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "b4 onResume rv_state check " + rv_state); //rv_state is always null
        if (rv_state != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "in onResume rv_state check");
            rv.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(rv_state);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unless you `finish()` your activity A1 while moving to A2, A1 is still in `onStop` state and not yet destroyed. Instance save methods are only called when an `Activity` is destroyed.

Comment: I added finish() method in OnPause and onSaveInstanceState for testing. Now while onDestroy is being called, onRestoreInstanceState is still not being called and rv_state is still null

Comment: Instead, you can use `onCreate(Bundle state)` method of A1. Even `onCreate()` receives the same `Bundle` as `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: I tried that. The bundle in onCreate is null  aswell